# Anagram Algorithm does not work 100% of the time

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, factorial, anagram

This is my anagram algorithm

```
   public static void anagram() {
    String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the word");
    char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();
    ArrayList<Integer> noOfRL = new ArrayList<>();
    int repeatedLetters = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        for (int k = i+1; k < word.length()-1; k++) {
            if (wordArray[i] == wordArray[k]) {
                repeatedLetters++;
                wordArray[k] = (char) (i+k);
            }

        }
        if (repeatedLetters != 1) {
            noOfRL.add(repeatedLetters);
        }
        repeatedLetters = 1;
    }
    double totalCombinations = factorial(word.length());
    double restrictions  = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < noOfRL.size(); i++){
        restrictions *= factorial(noOfRL.get(i));
    }
    double actualCombinations = totalCombinations/restrictions;
    System.out.println(actualCombinations);

}

public static double factorial(double number) {
    if (number > 1) {
        return number * factorial(number - 1);
    } else {
        return 1;

    }
}
```

It works fine for all normal words. 
However as soon as you input eeeeeee or aaaaaaaaa. etc...
the code fails to give the correct answer of 1. 
After debugging I realised that the number of repeated letters is always 1 less than the length of the string and therefore gives the wrong answer.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I can't get what you meant by `wordArray[k] = (char) (i+k);` Suppose you find the character at position `k==25` equals the one at `i==8`, this assignment will replace the `wordArray[25]` character with `(char)(25+8)` which is an exclamation mark `'!' == 33`. Why? That may make additional false 'repeated characters' later (say, if there is `'!'` at `wordArray[17]`)....

Comment: I'd suggest you to simply **sort** characters in the word, then scan it to find out repeated characters. They will be grouped together, so you can easily detect them by comparing adjacent positions, and you can easily count them by scanning for the next different character.

Answer (score 0):

Your nested for loop is needlessly complicated, I would say.
You could use streams to aggregate identical letters and reduce the size of the resulting list via your factorial function.
The result might look like this:

```
public static void anagram() {
    final String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the word");
    final double restrictions = com.google.common.primitives.Chars
            .asList(word.toCharArray())
            .stream()
            .collect(
                    collectingAndThen(
                            groupingBy(Function.identity()),
                            map -> map.values().stream()
                                    .mapToDouble(List::size)
                                    .filter(l -> l > 1)
                                    .reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * factorial(b))));
    final double totalCombinations = factorial(word.length());
    final double actualCombinations = totalCombinations / restrictions;
    System.out.println(actualCombinations);
}
```